# Counting in an access report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a database for different job courses with multiple reports, in these reports I want to show the precentage of people that completed the course. To achieve this I need data from two different queries. One query contains the names of all the employees. And the second query contains the names of the people that completed a certain course. What would be the best aproach to achieve what I need?

I know there is a `Count()` function in access. But I dont know how to get data from two different queries. For easy reference lets say i use the flowing names. qryAllEmployees contains the fiels personal number and name. QryCourseCompleted contains the name and data of completion. The report is named rptCompleted, this report contains a field where I want to show the precentage of employees that completed the course.

I hope someone can help me. If additional information is needed please tell me! Thanks in advance for your time and efford!

Joeri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use such data directly as controlsource e.g. in a report, use [Domain Aggregate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-Functions-by-category-b8b136c3-2716-4d39-94a2-658ce330ed83) functions (scroll down a little).

In your case: [`DCount()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DCount-Function-f6b5d78b-ad0b-4e42-be7a-11a64acbf3d3) .

```
= DCount("*", "QryCourseCompleted") / DCount("*", "qryAllEmployees")
```

should work as controlsource of your report textbox (format as percent).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, got caught up in other work stuff. But it doesnt work for me. When I put your code '= DCount("*", "QryCourseCompleted") / DCount("*", "qryAllEmployees")' in the control source field of my textbox. It tells me the following _The expression you entered contains invalid syntax. You omitted an operand or operator, you enetered an invalid character or comma, or you entered text without surrouding it in quotation marks._ Hope you are willing to help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @J.Rommers: If you use a non-US version of Access, you may need to use `;` instead of `,` in the DCount calls.

Comment: Cool. This is a thing to remember for the future (e.g. when applying solutions you find on SO or otherwise) : in form and query design, `;` is your list/argument separator, while in SQL view and VBA it's `,`. Kinda annoying, but that's localization...

Comment: Yes I wont forget that now. I think it works the same in Excel. I just forgot about it, its working great now! Thanks again